# Disabling a CMD command for a User

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-command-prompt, command, shutdown

Let's say there are two accounts on Windows, Admin and User. Im running a program which shutdowns system in some ammount of time (using `shutdown /s /t`). Is there any way to disable `shutdown -a` for a User? (Except situation where i disable cmd for User from Admin account - because i want to run program on User).

Comment: Here is the similar topic, might be you can find something useful there. https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/430295-disable-cmd-for-all-users-but-administrators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a direct answer, but rather a mean workaround:

Instead of relying on shutdown timed by `shutdown.exe`, use some custom timing mechanism, either via another scheduled task or via some script, eg. vbscript.

At first step, trigger a timed `shutdown.exe` as before (or use some custom messaging mechanism), but after a predefined time force shutdown with `shutdown.exe /t 0`.

Comment: Oh, you're right! I'm not familiar with vbscript, but i can surely implement a simple timer in my program and force the shutdown with /t 0. Thanks! :)

Comment: And how can I run exe in the background after inputting some data? (in this case time until shutdown) Im programming in c++